Qt6 Application doesn't show System Tray when running as root in linux
My qt6 app worked well when built with a qt6.7.2 sdk installed with qt's official .run file, and the app used .so library from the sdk. Then I removed the sdk and rebuilt my app with qt6.8 from archlinux official repository. Then I found that it tells me kf.statusnotifieritem: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP when I run it with sudo and fails to show tray icon, while it works correctly when I run it as normal user.
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt6/plugins/ does not make it work well.
I have met with such error before, is it not recommended to run qt app as root? How can I fix it or I had better not run GUI qt app as root? Thanks.
My CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myproject VERSION 2.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS on)

include_directories("include")

IF (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")
include_directories("/usr/include/qt6/")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/cmake/")
ELSEIF (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
#
ENDIF (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release")
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
endif()

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui)
add_executable(myproject main.cpp myproject.cpp myproject.qrc myproject.rc config.ui monitor.ui)
target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Gui)

output of pacman -Q |grep qt
appstream-qt 1.0.3-1
bluez-qt 6.7.0-1
fcitx5-qt 5.1.8-1
kdsoap-qt6 2.2.0-1
layer-shell-qt 6.2.2-1
libaccounts-qt 1.17-1
liblastfm-qt5 1.1.0-1
libmygpo-qt5 1.1.0-3
libqaccessibilityclient-qt6 0.6.0-1
modemmanager-qt 6.7.0-1
networkmanager-qt 6.7.0-1
phonon-qt6 4.12.0-4
phonon-qt6-vlc 0.12.0-2
polkit-qt6 0.200.0-1
poppler-qt6 24.09.0-4
pulseaudio-qt 1.6.0-1
qca-qt6 2.3.9-3
qt5-base 5.15.15+kde+r132-1
qt5-declarative 5.15.15+kde+r25-1
qt5-location 5.15.15+kde+r7-1
qt5-multimedia 5.15.15+kde+r2-1
qt5-svg 5.15.15+kde+r5-1
qt5-tools 5.15.15+kde+r3-2
qt5-translations 5.15.15-1
qt5-wayland 5.15.15+kde+r60-1
qt5-webchannel 5.15.15+kde+r3-1
qt5-webengine 5.15.17-7
qt5-x11extras 5.15.15-1
qt6-5compat 6.8.0-1
qt6-base 6.8.0-1
qt6-charts 6.8.0-1
qt6-declarative 6.8.0-2
qt6-imageformats 6.8.0-1
qt6-multimedia 6.8.0-1
qt6-multimedia-ffmpeg 6.8.0-1
qt6-positioning 6.8.0-1
qt6-quick3d 6.8.0-1
qt6-quicktimeline 6.8.0-1
qt6-sensors 6.8.0-1
qt6-shadertools 6.8.0-1
qt6-speech 6.8.0-1
qt6-svg 6.8.0-1
qt6-tools 6.8.0-1
qt6-translations 6.8.0-1
qt6-virtualkeyboard 6.8.0-1
qt6-wayland 6.8.0-1
qt6-webchannel 6.8.0-1
qt6-webengine 6.8.0-5
qt6-websockets 6.8.0-1
qtkeychain-qt6 0.14.3-1


Technically there's no absolute problem with running programs as root (or as any user different than the one running the current graphics server), but it's generally discouraged for security reasons. The problem has nothing to do with the program itself, but with the fact that you're running the program as a different user, and therefore the environment is a bit inconsistent to what a normal program would expect. Try running it like this: KDE_FULL_SESSION="" sudo <program>. Eventually, if it works, consider unsetting that env by code when detecting that it's running as a different user.

Note: in general, you should avoid running any program as root or with sudo unless you really need it like that. At the very least, you shall consider using a proper SetUID bit on the executable (as long as you know its implications and risks) so that you still have the permissions to act as root (or group) to access determinate system objects, but you're still running as the current user.

Thanks, for your help, though KDE_FULL_SESSION="" doesn't work, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="" makes my program runs normally.

The final solution is to unset XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP or export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="".

I was afraid of that. Unfortunately, each DE may set those variables in different ways, usually quite inconsistently. As already said, running on a different user may present some quite difficult (and unpredictable) challenges, even within the same wm/de but just using different versions, not to mention the fact that the user may choose to define or alter those variables. That's why, as said, you should consider running the app as the current user, eventually using SetUID. And, even in that case, that may not always work, if, for instance, the user alters those variables somewhere else.

I have tried using suid for my program and it told me the same error.

Do you mean that you changed the suid and running the program from the logged in user still gave you the same error? That seems unlikely, especially since you expressively wrote that running the program as a normal user does not result in that. For obvious reasons, still using sudo is completely pointless even the suid was changed, as what matters is the environment of the running user.

I used chown root:root myprogram and chmod a+s myprogram so the permission is now -rwsr-sr-x, then I execute it as normal user without sudo, is this what you meant by "SetUID"?
